# Ide/Editor with split ability, C++ highlighting,

Tags: ide, editor

I would like a C++ editor/IDE with the following features

- Runs under Linux
- Split Windows
- Separate buffer selection for each subwindow
- Highlighting
- Auto indentation
- Code completion
- Session saving
- Multiple simultaneous sessions
- Multiple windows
- Friendly to custom Makefiles
- Built-in terminal emulator

I use Jedit like this:
http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/5266/jeditsnap.png
and quiet satisfied with it but it lacks multiple sessions and terminal emulator. Most of the IDEs I used don't support splitting, or support it poorly, and QTCreator is not very good for non-qt projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all You've written can be achieved using Vim (http://vim.org) however it seems like a pretty hardcore solution.

Other than that you could try Eclipse with CDE plugins.

You can have sessions saved using for example Mylyn's per-task context support. You can run multiple instances of this IDE.

I don't know right now how to do split window, but  googling for "eclipse split window" shows pretty much answers to this problem.

Comment: Here is a quick video tutorial: http://addisu.taddese.com/blog/split-windowview-using-eclipse/

Comment: Not exactly how I wanted it but quiet good. I accepted this answer because of the link you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Surely [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Tried that, got irritated from repeating too many M-u M-x combos and unable to make it remmeber last setup. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Emacs like vim can be a hardcore ide, but be serious, the entry level is so steep!

Comment: @Atilla Filiz: If you make sure you have menus available then anything you can't remember is accessible through a normal menu just like any other IDE. The main advantage is that you can configure virtually any part of Emacs behaviour just using code (in the .emacs file).

Answer (score 0):

vim can do all those things.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org) a try. It's a Gnome application, but works well for any C/C++ programming.

Answer (score -1):

1. [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx)
2. [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)